# how to remove only font size when i select removeformat in nicedit.js file

Tags: javascript, nicedit

I am using Nic-edit library in my code for editing text area.
When I select font format it is not applying to the selected text because the font size present in the text is overriding.

This is a custom h1 heading with overridden font size.

when I select h1 format from Nic-editor for whole text then it needs to convert into h1 format including "this" as well.

but I am getting "this" with 1 font size and rest getting h1 format because of font size .

Comment: Im not familiar with nic-edit but for me, sounds like an expected behavior. Also checking the documentation of nic-edit, looks like there isn´t any built-in way to add an custom behavior. Tested also in TinyMCE which im more familiar and have the same behavior.